# Sci-fi story (or novel?) written in the '60s-'70s about man who wakes up in a parallel reality where WWII never happened

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

A male protagonist wakes up in a parallel reality where he is married. His alternate self is not a very nice person. WWII never happened and the society is behind in technological progress compared to the original reality. He eventually ends up back in his original reality and looks for the the woman who was his wife in the alternate one.

Comment: Could this be "Random Quest" by John Wyndham, as asked here? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/247056/tv-alternate-world-story-no-ww2/247059#247059

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez You should post that as an answer. The previous question was about a TV programme, not the short story it was based on, so it would be good to have an answer about the story even though it is a duplicate.

Comment: @JohnRennie Done!

Answer (score 7):

This sounds very much like *[Random Quest](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57821)*, a short story  by John Wyndham first published in 1961.

It deals with a physicist named Colin Trafford, who was  flung into an alternate universe in which Hitler never came to power, WW2 did not occur, and India was still part of the British Empire. He finds that in this alternate universe he is a romantic novelist. Reading through the novels, written by his alternate self, he was struck how the man's character had become increasingly unpleasant. The alternate Colin was married to an Ottilie Harshom, but was cheating on her with various affairs. Colin falls deeply in love with her, and remedies the marital difficulties, but is suddenly transported back to his own world. Here he spends his time trying to track down her counterpart, assisted by her unusual name.

The short story is available online at the Internet Library, in Wyndham's collection of short stories "[Consider her ways](https://archive.org/details/considerherwayso00wynd)".